Using C# System.Diagnostics to launch R to process information and pass results back to console
I have a legacy C# application that uses datatables in its operations.
I need to pass information from a datatable in a C# program to R; then get R to process the data using the instructions from a script file do some work on the passed data; then get the results from R back to C#.
To explain, I have written a short console app.
I've tried this so many different ways, but the result is always the same:
System.IO.IOException: 'The pipe is being closed.'

This error happens on the first iteration. I'm not sure if R successfully opens, but if it does, it closes immediately.
EDIT: after consulting the MS Docs and reading through this link, it seems that the initialization of the Rscript.exe isn't occurring even before the StreamWriter starts up (IO error above). This is the error I get on the MainModule when I set a breakpoint after "process.start()"
'process.MainModule' threw an exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'

This is odd because initially, I was using a 64bit version of R and had my solution configuration setup for x64.
After reading that exception, I installed a lower version of R (3.6.3) that had a 32bit exe version and tried that. Same error regardless.
So, I'm unsure why Rscript.exe is not being spawned. I think I've tried every option that I can think of (i.e., 32bit, 64bit).
-- END EDIT --
For the arguments, I have tried so many combinations (here are just a couple):

Arguments = "-c " + scriptPath,
Arguments = scriptPath,
Arguments = "-c -q --vanilla --file=" + scriptPath  (EDIT: addition)

I have successfully used similar code to send commands to Rscript.exe from a C# program and capture the output back to the console using a different program, but the 1st argument above was used.
I have also written many different R scripts--but, I don't think those have mattered at this point as the process shuts down immediately.
Here is the C# program:
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

public class RandomDataToR
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create data
        int row_cnt = 10;
        double x_bar = 50;
        double sd = 10;

        // Generate random numbers with mean x_bar and StdDev sd
        double[] data = GenerateRandomData(row_cnt, x_bar, sd);

        // Create a DataTable
        DataTable dt = CreateDataTable(data);

        // Send data to R program
        string rAppPath = @"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.3.0\bin\Rscript.exe"; 
        string rScript = @"C:\Temp\ConsoleApp\get_output.r";  
        string results = SendDataToExe(dt, rAppPath, rScript);
        Console.WriteLine(results);
    }

    private static double[] GenerateRandomData(int count, double mean, double stdDev)
    {
        double[] data = new double[count];
        var random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {

            double u1 = 1.0 - random.NextDouble(); 
            double u2 = 1.0 - random.NextDouble();
            double rndStdNorm = Math.Sqrt(-2.0 * Math.Log(u1)) * Math.Sin(2.0 * Math.PI * u2);
            data[i] = mean + stdDev * rndStdNorm;
        }

        return data;
    }

    private static DataTable CreateDataTable(double[] data)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        dataTable.Columns.Add("Data", typeof(double));
        foreach (double value in data)
        {
            dataTable.Rows.Add(Math.Round(value, 2));
        }
        return dataTable;
    }

    private static string SendDataToExe(DataTable dt, string exePath, string scriptPath)
    {
        string unixSyleScript = scriptPath.Replace("\\", "/");

        // Serialize DataTable to a CSV format
        StringBuilder csvData = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            csvData.AppendLine(row["Data"].ToString());
        }

        // Setup the process start info
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
        {
            FileName = exePath,
            Arguments = "--vanilla --file=" + unixSyleScript,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        // Execute Rscript and send the data
        using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = startInfo })
        {
            process.Start();

            using (StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput)
            {
                if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
                {
                sw.Write(csvData.ToString());
                sw.Flush();
                }
            }

            // Read the output from the R script until "**DONE**" is received
            string output;
            string errors;
            do
            {
                output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                errors = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
            } while (output != null && !output.Equals("**DONE**"));

            if (process != null)
            {
                process.WaitForExit();  // Wait for the process to finish
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(errors))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Errors from Rscript: " + errors);
            }

            return output;
        }
    }
}

Here is the R program "get_output.r":
# Read data from standard input
data <- scan(what = numeric(), sep = "\n")

# Print results
cat("***     RESULTS     ***\n")
cat(as.vector(data), sep = '\n')
cat("***********************\n")

# Signal completion by writing a character to standard output
cat("*** DONE PROCESSING ***\n")

Thanks for any help.
2nd EDIT
I added the following code to see if R would work from C# at all and this replacement method worked fine with no problems.
private static string sendDataToExe(string exePath)
{
    string rCommand = "data <- rnorm(100, mean=0, sd=1); print(summary(data))";

    try
    {
        ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = exePath,
            Arguments = $"-e \"{rCommand}\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = processStartInfo })

        {
            process.Start();

            string result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

            process.WaitForExit();

            return result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
        return null;
    }
}

